# Continous file update, recursive function?

Tags: java, c++, c, file, function

I want to append information onto a file based on user selection of minutes (1 min, 15, 30, 45min etc) through radio buttons. for each radio button there are case in switch statement. I am finding it difficult to update the file on a regular interval, continously, does anyone know how to do it based on whatever minute has been chosen. time_int is current time, update_point is the next interval point in which the file needs to be updated? so please help with the UPDATEFILE() method.

```
  public void radioStartTime(int t) {

    time_int = System.currentTimeMillis(); //time radio button is clicked, clock      the time on click
    System.out.println(sdf.format(time_int));

    /* a case/situation for different radio button selected*/
    switch (t) {

    case 1:
        update_point = time_int + (1*60000);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(update_point));
        UPDATEFILE????(1);
    break;

            .....
```

Answer (score 2):

3 ways you may consider to go:

- if it is free for you to include new libraries, you could check Quartz scheduler. it could handle many complex scheduler use cases.
- you could also check java.util.Timer. it could (from javadoc:)***schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals***. the latter part is exactly what you need.
- write your own thread and sleep/wait mechanism to achieve your goal.

anyway, I don't think recursion is the right way to solve scheduling problems.

Comment: thats too complicated for me, can i just use a do while loop somehow??

Comment: @user1106130 that sounds like the way(3). you create a thread to do the task(file update), and wrap it with while, like: while(true or other condidtion){this.wait(yourinterval); updateFile();}, however you have to take care and handle some details, thread safe, blocking etc.